# Milo OPC UA - create a server with username and password

Tags: opc, opc-ua, milo

I'm new to OPC UA and I want to create a server that requires username and password in order to authenticate user, how is that possible in Milo OPC ?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: @Thangadurai Milo docs are not available to check how it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered by the example server: https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/master/milo-examples/server-examples/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/examples/server/ExampleServer.java

Create a `UsernameIdentityValidator` and set it on the config builder.